# How do I map one-to-one on 3 table in hibernate with xml?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've some table with one-to-one relationship like these :

[image: Sample table]

How can I map these tables ?
I just try to map with xml by following how-to tutorial from [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/)-many-to-many mapping , it's work but I doesn't need result as Set.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm interested in this answer. I had this exact situation before and had to do a pretty hacky workaround since at the time I couldn't find any support for it.

Comment: Maybe you should specify the versions of the frameworks you're using.

Comment: What kind of result do you need?

Comment: @peter.petrov : I'm using hibernate 4.3.0.

Comment: Is the middle table required to your design? Which relationship do you want to get one-to-one or many-to-many?

Comment: @JuanManuel : Person's object, just like many-to-one.

Comment: @RomanC : For now, still required it. But in nearly future I will drop it if I can't find another way to deal with it.

Comment: In this case you need to make two one-to-one associations (if on-to-one you didn't answer my question), next should it be unidirectional or bidirectional?

Comment: @RomanC : One to one and unidirectional.

Comment: One to one on three tables in which direction?